# Splitting natural number into a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am looking for a way to make `split(A, B, L)` to exhaustively enumerate a B-elements list L such that sum of L's elements equals to A.

#### Example

```
?- split(s(s(s(s(0)))), s(s(s(0))), L)  % splitting 3 to 4 natural numbers
L = [0, 0, 0, s(s(s(0)))];
L = [0, 0, s(0), s(s(0))];
L = [0, 0, s(s(0)), s(0)];
L = [0, 0, s(s(s(0))), 0];
...
L = [s(0), 0, 0, s(s(0))];
...
L = [s(s(s(0))), 0, 0, 0];
false.
```

My idea was to extend a list from smaller ones; for example, if `split(3, B, [e1, e2, e3])` is true, `split(4, B+a, [a, e1, e2, e3])` is also true (the inline code is not accurate; I used to convey my idea).

Thus I wrote a code as follows.

```
split(0, 0, []).
split(s(0), B, [B]).
split(s(A), X, [Y|L]) :- split(A, B, L), add(Y, B, X).
```

Where

```
add(0, B, B).
add(s(A), B, s(C)) :- add(A, B, C).
```

However, when I run this code, the program doesn't stop and fails.
How should I fix it? Any advices would help.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of a number.
A possible solution, using SWI prolog, could be:

```
weak_compositions(ListLen,ListP,Number):-
    length(List,ListLen),
    maplist(between(0, Number), List),
    sum_list(List,Number),
    maplist(to_peano,List,ListP).

to_peano(0,0):- !.
to_peano(N,s(S1)):-
    N1 is N - 1,
    to_peano(N1,S1).

?- weak_compositions(4,L,3).
L = [0, 0, 0, s(s(s(0)))]
L = [0, 0, s(0), s(s(0))]
L = [0, 0, s(s(0)), s(0)]
L = [0, 0, s(s(s(0))), 0]
...
```

Comment: This does not keeping a running total, so is not performant. Tested with `time(findall(L, weak_compositions(3, L, 3), Ls)).` (816 inferences) vs `time(findall(L, split_lists_peano(s(s(s(0))), s(s(s(0))), L), Ls)).` (154 inferences)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly rearranged arguments (for improved determinism, using first-argument indexing):

```
split_lists_peano(0, 0, []).
split_lists_peano(s(ElemCount), Sum, [Elem|LstPeano]) :-
    peano_count_up(0, Sum, Elem),
    peano_add(Elem, Sum0, Sum),
    split_lists_peano(ElemCount, Sum0, LstPeano).

peano_count_up(Limit, Limit, Limit) :- !.
peano_count_up(Upto, _Limit, Upto).
peano_count_up(Upto, Limit, Count) :-
    peano_count_up(s(Upto), Limit, Count).

peano_add(0, N, N).
peano_add(s(N), M, s(Sum)) :-
    % Decrement towards 0
    peano_add(N, M, Sum).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- split_lists_peano(s(s(s(0))), s(s(s(0))), P).
P = [0, 0, s(s(s(0)))] ;
P = [0, s(0), s(s(0))] ;
P = [0, s(s(0)), s(0)] ;
P = [0, s(s(s(0))), 0] ;
P = [s(0), 0, s(s(0))] ;
P = [s(0), s(0), s(0)] ;
P = [s(0), s(s(0)), 0] ;
P = [s(s(0)), 0, s(0)] ;
P = [s(s(0)), s(0), 0] ;
P = [s(s(s(0))), 0, 0].
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar question: [[0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74411844/a-function-that-lists-all-combination-of-addition-and-its-answer-in-prolog) [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74377227/prolog-making-a-4-argument-add-function)

Using `foldl/4`:

```
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :-
    nat(X).

% -X + Y = Z
sub(X, Y, Z) :-
    add(X, Z, Y).
```

An example of query:

```
?- length(Ns, 3), nat(S), foldl(sub, Ns, S, 0).
   Ns = [0,0,0], S = 0
;  Ns = [0,0,s(0)], S = s(0)
;  Ns = [0,s(0),0], S = s(0)
;  Ns = [s(0),0,0], S = s(0)
;  Ns = [0,0,s(s(0))], S = s(s(0))
;  ... .
```

Comment: Please always put an answer (description) to your queries such that individuals immediately see what your solution is about.